rsortino/ColorizeNet does not appear to have a file named config.json
I want to run https://huggingface.co/rsortino/ColorizeNet locally on my PC with a GPU. I followed the instructions at https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation (all i did was conda install conda-forge::transformers) to set this up, and came up with the following code:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("rsortino/ColorizeNet")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("rsortino/ColorizeNet")

tokenizer.save_pretrained("colorizeNet")
model.save_pretrained("colorizeNet")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("colorizeNet")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("colorizeNet")

But when I run it, I get the following error:
Exception has occurred: OSError
rsortino/ColorizeNet does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/rsortino/ColorizeNet/main' for available files.

Which makes sense - the repo does indeed not have a config.json file. How can I get this model running? I'm new to running models and to huggingface.
